# add shape dynamically to activereports

Tags: activereports

I've got a kinda requirement in which there is a kinda graph (static picture) on a page. In that picture I need to plot some points dynamically. That means using a shape filled with blue color. The number of points is floating depending upon the number of applicants choosen. How can I make it work or how can I add new elements to report at runtime. Am working in ASP.nET using VB and the AR version is 6.2

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your query right,then you want to plot some points depending on the dynamic data.

A suggestion would be to make use of [Chart](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/arHOWUseCharts.html) control in report. The chart can be bound to anything from a list to an array and the data can be changed dynamically from time to time.

Moreover,you can set the [backcolor](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/arCONChartAndSeriesSpecificProperties.html) and other [properties](http://helpcentral.componentone.com/NetHelp/ActiveReports6/arCONChartControlItems.html) of the Chart control to give a look and feel of your choice.

Regards,
Mohita

Comment: I was able to make that. So I shared the code below.. Its a simple one.. But I missed that when I created it..

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if my question makes any confusion.. Actually I was able to make that. So am just sharing that code if it helpful for someone else.. I put this to the report start event. (We are not permitted to make this in details event)

```
 Dim pic As New DataDynamics.ActiveReports.Picture
 pic.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/images/circle.gif", cl)))
 pic.SizeMode = SizeModes.Zoom
 Detail1.Controls.Add(pic)
```